# Do I need to carry photograph for UK visa interview?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

It's a standard UK visa for a US green card holder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, they will capture a photo during the submission process.

> **2. Go to your appointment**
>
> You must book your biometric appointment at a US Department of Homeland Security application support centre (ASC) when you apply online. This is to have your photo and fingerprints taken (known as ‘biometric information’).

[USA: apply for a UK visa](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa#go-to-your-appointment)